# Android get an error when i try to setRequestProperty to HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android

i'm wrote simple download manager and i'm trying to set RESUME for all downloads. after googleing for how to do that. i know must be `setRequestProperty` for connection, but my code does not work and i get this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-882
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set request property after connection is made
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.setRequestProperty(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:510)
```

My code is:

```
URL url = new URL(downloadPath);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

final int fileSize = connection.getContentLength();

File file = new File(filepath);
if (file.exists() && fileSize == file.length()) {
    return;
} else if (file.exists()) {
    connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+(file.length())+"-");
}else
    connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloadedSize + "-");

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.connect();
```

how to resolve this problem and correctly set `setRequestProperty` to connection?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling `connection.getContentLength()` before you're calling `setRequestProperty()`. The content length is only available *after* you've made a request, at which point you can't set the request property...

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but one option is to use a `HEAD` request just to get the content length, and then make a *separate* request if you need to get just a portion of the data. Be aware that it's possible that the content length will change between requests, of course.

However, I would actually suggest keeping more metadata somewhere in your download manager - so that when you first start downloading the data, you keep a record of the total size, so that you don't need to make the `HEAD` request when resuming - you can tell just from the local information whether or not you've already downloaded a file. (This has the same problem in terms of content changing, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: thanks. then how to find contentLenght() and enable resume ability?

Comment: @mahdipishguy: See my edited answer. But it's important that you think about the request/response at an HTTP level - that makes it easier to understand why your current code failed, and may well help you diagnose other problems too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error than OP.

**WHY**
The problem is that when you try to set the params to the request to resume the download, you have to be disconnected from the Http.

The moment you invoke the method `connection.getContentLenght();` what happens is that `connection.connect();` so if you then try to set the properties to the connection you will get the error mentioned.

**FIX**
What I did was that I closed the connection to Http after I invoked the method `long totalFileSize = connection.getContentLength();`

`connection.disconnect()`//Disconnect from http

And after that you can set the the parameters you want to the connection and invoke `connection.connect()` whenever needed.

**TIP**
In my particular case I was trying to download a file and needed to support resumable downloads, so to do it what I did was:

- Check if file exists.
- If file exists then get the lenght of the file:

  `long bytesDownloaded = file.getLenght();`
- Use this lenght to set it to the connection so it can resume from exactly the bytes it was paused.
- Write the bytes to the end of the file.

Comment: This answer makes no sense.  You are disconnecting and then connecting right after?

Comment: I also thougth the exact same thing when I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should set properties before `getContentLength()`
2. If you set range equal to exist file length you will receive remain bytes when call `getContentLength()` so if content length was equal to "0" that means that file downloaded completely.

But if you want to build a download manager, @Jon Skeet's method is reasonable.

Edit:

> public abstract long getContentLength ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Tells the length of the content, if known.
>
> Returns the number of bytes of the content, or a negative number if
>   unknown. If the content length is known but exceeds Long.MAX_VALUE, a
>   negative number is returned.